# Flipping a card horizontally (keeping the height at 100%)

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

National Geographic has this [great little JavaScript game](https://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-content/richmedia/0/629/project/memory/memory.html) that includes sound and animation. In looking at the source code, I thought they were flipping the card by doing an `animate {width:0%}` followed by an `animate {width:100%}`, but my animation looks different than theirs:

```js
$(document).on('click','img',clicked)

function clicked() {
  $(this).animate({width:'0%'})
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-content/richmedia/0/629/project/memory/images/card_back_hard.png">
```

Q: How do you I get the card to flip horizontally rather than shrink to 0%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only one dimension of an `img` is specified then the value is applied to all dimensions to maintain the aspect ratio.

If you want to retain the `height`, set it to its initial value.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'img', clicked)

function clicked() {
  $(this).animate({
    width: '0%',
    height: $(this).height()
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-content/richmedia/0/629/project/memory/images/card_back_hard.png">
```

Comment: Now why didn't I think of that? I think it was because I was copying/pasting from their source code, but your answer makes perfect sense.